# nodejs webapp - wont "serve" pages

Tags: html, node.js

It only tells "Cannot GET /page" if ill try to lookup it.

Tree for project.

project-root

```
|-- models
|   |-- User.js
|-- routes
|   |-- authRoutes.js
|   |-- productRoutes.js
|-- public
|   |-- css
|   |   |-- styles.css
|   |-- js
|   |   |-- main.js
|-- views
|   |-- pages
    |-- login, and messages.
|-- server.js
```

server.js:

```
// Serve static files from 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Custom middleware to handle .html extension removal
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.path.endsWith('.html')) {
      const newPath = req.path.slice(0, -5); // Remove the .html extension
      return res.redirect(newPath);
    }
    next();
  });

// Serve HTML views from 'views' directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// Root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
  });

// Models
const User = require('./models/User');

// Routes
//..
//

// Start Server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './views' }); // Adjust the path based on your project structure
  });
});
```

Comment: Any routes should be defined outside listen(), not sure what that's doing in there. Also, there's no "/page" route defined, just the root "/"

Comment: yeah, forgot that it need to be served all routes and correct.